# Threaded DelayedJob workers dry up ActiveRecord connection pool

Tags: ruby, multithreading, activerecord, delayed-job, rufus-scheduler

I want to run jobs scheduling (with [rufus_scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/)) and processing (with [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/), DJ) with the ActiveRecord backend from the same jRuby process, but in different threads.

This works fine when just one DJ worker is in use, but when I set up multiple queues (with one worker per queue), the scheduler terminates with the following message:

```
rufus-scheduler intercepted an error:                                                                               
   job:                                                                                                                          
     Rufus::Scheduler::CronJob "*/10 * * * * *" {}                                                                   
   error:                                                                                                            
     ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError                                                                             
     could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use
```

This leads me to believe that the workers do not free the database connections upon termination of the job, but I have yet to find the relevant code. The amount of connections in the pool is configured to be 50.

The script is supposed to keep running until it receives `SIGTERM` and should have access to the Rails environment. A MWE is given below:

```
require './config/environment'

module Jobs
  class ExampleJob < ActiveJob::Base
    queue_as :system

    def perform
      puts 'Performing ExampleJob'
    end
  end
end

QUEUES = %i(system database).freeze
NUM_QUEUES = QUEUES.size

workers = []
worker_threads = []

NUM_QUEUES.times do |queue_number|
  worker = Delayed::Worker.new(quiet: false)
  worker.name = queue_number
  workers.append(worker)
  worker_threads.append(Thread.new do
    worker.start
  end)
end

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.cron '*/10 * * * * *' do
  puts 'Scheduled ExampleJob'
  Jobs::ExampleJob.perform_later
end

Signal.trap('TERM') do
  scheduler.shutdown
  workers.each do |worker|
    worker.stop
  end
end

scheduler.join
worker_threads.each do |thread|
  thread.join
end
```

Is there a way to get this to run properly?

Comment: There seem to be [all sorts of problems](https://ylan.segal-family.com/blog/2013/09/11/delayedjob-workers-are-not-thread-safe/) with using multiple threaded DelayedJob workers.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
module Jobs
  class ExampleJob < ActiveJob::Base
    queue_as :system

    def perform
      puts 'Performing ExampleJob'
    end

    after_perform do
      ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
    end
  end
end
```

?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this does not solve the problem.